# How to use a variable reference instead of it's value because it's nil at compilation time?

Tags: macros, elixir, decorator, phoenix-framework

I'm wrapping my Appsignal instrumentation and everything works fine.

```
def handle_event("submit", %{"waitlist" => params}, socket) do
  live_view_action(__MODULE__, "submit", socket, fn ->
    {:noreply, socket}
  end)
end
```

I wanted to move this to a decorator so I could do something like this:

```
@decorate instrument("submit")
def handle_event("submit", %{"waitlist" => params}, socket) do
  {:noreply, socket}
end

# And in my decorator:

import Appsignal.Phoenix.LiveView, only: [live_view_action: 4]

def get_socket(context) do
  Enum.find(context.args, fn arg ->
    [{_, type} | _] = IEx.Info.info(arg)

    if type == "tuple" && elem(arg, 0) == :socket do
      arg
    end
  end)
end

def instrument(name, body, context) do
  quote do
    socket = unquote(get_socket(context))

    live_view_action(unquote(context.module), unquote(name), socket, fn ->
      unquote(body)
    end)
  end
end
```

`socket` is always `nil` in the context at compilation time so I can't even run my project.

How can I use the *value* of socket at runtime where I know the `socket` won't be `nil`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with decorators, but it seems like yours could be a problem with macro hygiene. What does the result of `get_socket(context)` look like? If it's more like `{:socket, [], __MODULE__}` than `{:socket, [], nil}`, that could be your problem.

You might try replacing `unquote(get_socket(context))` with `unquote(Macro.var(:socket, nil))`?

See [Macro.var/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Macro.html#var/2)